# Wireless doesn't turn off via physical switch

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have a laptop here that I can't seem to turn wireless off on via the switch.  While the obvious choice is hardware failure, it's nearly a brand new Dell Precision M6600 and I hesitate to jump to conclusions.

The physical switch on the system will not toggle wifi on or off; it is always on.  I can disable it via Windows (Win 7 Pro), or simply disconnect from the network, but when I do it does not remember the wifi passwords, which may be a separate issue.

Right now I have it set to prioritize wired for traffic via setting the Metric option on both.

Does anybody have any experience with something similar?

Comment: If the physical switch is broken there isn't much you can do.  Does Dell offer software to manage your wireless connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireless password: Network and Sharing Center -> Manage Wireless Networks -> [select Wifi name] Properties -> Security tab -> check the box "Remember my credentials..."
Regarding the laptop wireless radio, most new laptops have settings for what the "wireless on/off" switch controls in the BIOS. For Dells, the boot to BIOS option is usually F2 when you first turn the computer on. Look around the system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a hardware failure has not occurred, you might want to check your BIOS settings to see which devices, if any, are set to be controlled by the switch. Usually Bluetooth adapter can also be turned on/off using the same switch.

P.S: I'm using Dell Latitude E5530.